# How do I hide the drive icons of my other partitions from the desktop?

Tags: 10.04, icons

I have the hard disk icon for each of my partitions on my Gnome desktop.

I want a clean look, how do I hide them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Type "gconf-editor" into a terminal window to run the Configuration Editor.
2. In the left hand tree, browse to apps / nautilus / desktop
3. In the right hand side, untick the "volumnes_visible" option.

Close the configuration editor. You may have to restart for the changes to take effect.

You can find more information on [How-To Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/hide-removable-drive-icons-from-your-ubuntu-desktop/).

Answer (score 1):

Also take a look at [Ubuntu Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/).  It's got a lot of settings that are in gconf-editor in a nice gui setup.

Comment: +1: a downvote with no explanation isn't very useful. Is it because Tweak doesn't work, or because it isn't part of the Gnome suite? It certainly can't be that the answer failed to address the question.

Comment: I'm not sure why I was downvoted, and decided to not comment snarkily last night, lest my reputation drop more. Thanks for the support, msw. And I think it does answer the question. It's not in the repos, but it's a nice all-in-one program to change settings without using gconf-editor. I do agree that gconf-editor is the more "correct" way to go about things though.

Answer (score 1):

To Hide Selected Partitions

If you wish to prevent certain partitions or drives appearing on the desktop, you can create a udev rule, for example `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-local.rules:`

```
KERNEL=="sdaX", ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE}="1"
KERNEL=="sdaY", ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE}="1"
```

Would show all partitions with the exception of sdaX and sdaY on your desktop.

Notice, if you are using udisk2 the above will not work, due to the UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE no longer being supported, instead you must use UDISKS_IGNORE as follows

```
KERNEL=="sdaX", ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}="1"
KERNEL=="sdaY", ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}="1"
```

This answer was culled from: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xfce4#Hide_Selected_Partitions
and though it's Arch and xfce it applies since Ubuntu uses /etc/udev/rules.d
And udisks is installed as part of gvfs if I'm not mistaken.
:-).

Answer (score 0):

[ailurus](http://code.google.com/p/ailurus/) which can be installed from this [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~ailurus/+archive/ppa) makes it easy. Once you install it with

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ailurus/ppa && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ailurus
```